# How to Return Distinct Values with ng-repeat (no duplicates)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a multipage form with AngularJS & UI Router. The first page gives the user option buttons to select which way they would like to filter through a list of movies (title, genre, or rating).

I'm using a switch statement to filter through what is shown on the second page. If the "title" button is clicked, then only titles are shown. If the user clicks "genre" then they will see the available genres, etc.

For the most part, my switch statement is working, however I run into errors when I try to show the available genres or ratings because I do not want duplicates. I tried using Angular's `unique: 'genre'`, but when I add that, it returns nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

My HTML:

```
<label>Available Movies</label>
    <div class="form-group" ng-controller="formController">
        <h3>What Button was clicked: </h3>
            <div ng-switch on="Data.sortType">
                <div ng-switch-when="title">Title</div>
                <div ng-switch-when="genre">Genre</div>
                <div ng-switch-when="rating">Rating</div>
            </div>
        <h4>Show results: </h4>
     <div ng-switch on="Data.sortType">
         <div ng-switch-when="title">
              <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">{{movie.title}}</div>
         </div>

         <!-- Here's where I run into trouble: --> 
         <div ng-switch-when="genre">
             <div ng-repeat="movie in movies | unique: 'genre'">{{movie.genre}}</div>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="rating">
              <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">{{movie.rating}}</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('movieApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

.factory('Data', function() {

    return { sortType: ''}; 
 })
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    // route to show our basic form (/form)
    .state('orderForm', {
        url: '/orderForm',
        templateUrl: 'orderForm.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('orderForm.step1', {
        url: '/step1',
        templateUrl: 'step1.html'
    })
     .state('orderForm.step2', {
        url: '/step2',
        templateUrl: 'step2.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/orderForm/step1');
 })

 .controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.Data = Data; 

    //Create lists of Drinks:
    $scope.movies = [
        {title:'Get Hard ', genre: 'Comedy', rating: 'R'},
        {title:'Cinderella', genre: 'Romance', rating: 'PG'},
        {title:'Avengers ', genre: 'Action', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Hot Pursuit', genre: 'Comedy', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Age of Adaline', genre: 'Romance', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Pitch Perfect 2', genre: 'Musical', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Longest Ride', genre: 'Romance', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Furious 7', genre: 'Action', rating: 'PG13'},
        {title:'Home', genre: 'Adventure', rating: 'PG'},
        {title:'Insurgent', genre: 'Action', rating: 'PG13'}
    ];
}]);
```

Comment: you need to use `unique` filter which has been all ready written in `ui-bootstrap` module

Comment: That sounds interesting, I found this website: (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) but I'm not sure how I would implement it in my code. Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="movie.genre for movie in movies | unique: 'genre'">{{movie.genre}}</div>
```

You will need to install some dependencies:

**1.** In your terminal, go to your project and run to install angular-ui-utils unique:

```
bower install angular-ui-utils#bower-unique
```

**2.** Require the unique.js file by adding this to your project below your angular script:

```
<!-- angular script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- unique script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/unique.js"></script>
```

**3.** Add unique as a module to your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.unique'])
```

Comment: Hi @Alex Pan, I tried both: `<div ng-repeat="movie.genre in movies | unique: 'genre'">{{movie.genre}}</div>` and  `<div ng-repeat="movie.genre for movie in movies | unique: 'genre'">{{movie.genre}}</div>`... unfortunately both return nothing.

Comment: @user3281388, I updated my answer with how you can add the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Alex pan - don't laugh, but i've never used my terminal before, so I'm trying to figure out how to get that to work! I'm struggling with how to find my project! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3281388, no worries! Let me know if you would like to pair program and I can walk you through it.

Comment: How would you suggest we pair program?

Comment: We can continue the discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77659/discussion-between-alex-pan-and-user3281388)

Comment: Just follow what Alex  has said. Its working perfectly fine.Here is the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/yFp6l9lq4NbrPu0hdGMq?p=preview for working copy. Could you confirm if you this working ?